# Reading binary file by parts

Tags: javascript, filereader, arraybuffer

I'm trying to read binary file using JavaScript. The first part of the file contains JSON, which I need to get and then the rest of the file, which I do not require.
The first 4 bytes is length of json string in little endian byte order, then json string and then binary data, which is not required.
I wrote following code, which is working:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file-input" />
    </body>
<script>
    function readSingleFile(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            return;
        }
        //console.log(file);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            var dataView = new DataView(reader.result, 0);
            var jsonLen = dataView.getInt32(0, true);
            //console.log(jsonLen);

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(reader.result, 4);
            var jsonStr = '';
            for (a = 0; a < jsonLen; a++) {
                jsonStr += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[a]);
            }
            //console.log(jsonStr);
            var jsonObj = obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
            console.log(jsonObj);
        }

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    
    document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
</html>
```

I have several questions:

1. Is it possible to read file partly, only stated beginning? The file could be big (100mb) and I only need first part of it, which is small (up to 1mb) comparing to the binary part which goes after json string and which I do not need.
2. Is the bit related to getting json string is right? Can it be optimized somehow to get string from array like "from" and "to"?
3. Initializing DataView and Uint8Array are they consume a lot of memory corresponding to the file length or they just contain reference to ArrayBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to first and main question is to use file.slice function. Updated code now looks as follow, which also resolves second and third questions:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file-input" />
    </body>
<script>
    var jsonStartPos = 4;
    
    function readSingleFile(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            return;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var dataView = new DataView(e.target.result, 0);
            var jsonLen = dataView.getInt32(0, true);
            
            var jsonReader = new FileReader();
            jsonReader.onload = function (e) {
                processJson(e.target.result);
            }
            var jsonBlob = file.slice(jsonStartPos, jsonLen + jsonStartPos);
            jsonReader.readAsText(jsonBlob);
        }
        var blob = file.slice(0, jsonStartPos);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        
    }
    
    function processJson(jsonStr) {
        var jsonObj = obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        console.log(jsonStr);
        console.log(jsonObj);
    }
    
    document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
</html>
```